# puppeteer call itself 2-3 time

Tags: node.js, angular, express, puppeteer

I am trying to make a pdf for the currently rendered page in my browser. I use Angular 11 and nodejs for the server. All working fine but when I check my pdf directory I found for a one-call it generate 3 pdf, then I debug my code and found my API is calling 3 times but I get a response only once.

component.ts

```
  downlode(id: any) {
    this.spinner = true;
    this.pdf_downlode.downlode_pdf(id).subscribe((res: Blob) => {
      console.log('res');
      saveAs(res, 'report.pdf');
      this.spinner = false;
    });
  }
```

service.ts

```
  get_record(id: any) {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.convert}/${id}`);
  }
```

api.js

```
router.get('/downlode/:id', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('downlode api call');
  const id = req.params.id;
  let url = `http://localhost:4200/temp/${id}`;
  try {
    const filename = Date.now();

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    });

    await page.pdf({
      path: path.join(__dirname, `../PublicPdf/${filename}.pdf`),
      printBackground: true,
      format: 'A4',
    });

    await page.close();
    await browser.close().then();
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `../PublicPdf/${filename}.pdf`));

    console.log('response send');
  } catch (error) {
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    res.json({ err: 1, message: error.message });
  }
  // fs.unlinkSync(path.join(__dirname, `../PublicPdf/${filename}.pdf`));
});
```

In my console, I got output order like this:-

> **downlode api call**
> **response send**,
> **downlode api call**
> **response send**,
> **downlode api call**
> **response send**